# JAVA Hyphenator using Coldfusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, hyphenation, javaloader

I was hoping someone can help with the implementation of [TeXHyphenator-J](https://sourceforge.net/projects/texhyphj/) using CFML.

I am using the JavaLoader.cfc to create a ColdFusion object of TeXHyphenator-J (as in the code below). When running the code I don't get any errors and a string is returned. However it isn't hyphenated?

```
<!--- Load Javaloader --->
<cfset paths    = arrayNew(1)>
<cfset paths[1] = expandPath("assets/Hyphenator/texhyphj.jar")>
<cfset loader   = createObject("component", "assets.javaloader.JavaLoader").init(paths)>

<!--- Create buffered stream to TeX file --->
<cfset FileInputStream = createobject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream").init(expandPath("assets/Hyphenator/hyphen.tex"))>
<cfset BufferedInputStream = createobject("java","java.io.BufferedInputStream").init(FileInputStream)>

<!--- Initiate Hyphenator --->
<cfset h = loader.create('net.davidashen.text.Hyphenator').init()>
<!--- load the TeX table into Hyphenator --->
<cfset h.loadTable(BufferedInputStream)>
<!--- Get hyphenated string, Hyphenator should return as-so-ci-ate --->
<cfset retStr = h.hyphenate('associate')>

<cfdump var="#retStr#">
```

Answer (score 0):

> however it isn't hyphenated

While not immediately obvious, the returned value actually *is* hyphenated. The chosen [hyphen character, ie \u00ad](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ad/index.htm) just is not visible. Dumping each character in the string shows the soft hyphens have an ascii value of 173:

```
97  : a
115 : s
173 : ­    <== soft hyphen
115 : s
111 : o
173 : ­    <== soft hyphen
99  : c
105 : i
97  : a
116 : t
101 : e
```

So one simple solution would be to replace that character with a standard hyphen:

```
newString = replace(retStr, chr(173), "-", "all")
```

Side note, running the same example directly in java also yielded "as-so-ciate", *not* "as-so-ci-ate".